# Texture Pack on Multiplayer Game

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, minecraft-resource-packs, minecraft-addons

I am playing on a Hermitcraft-style world in MCBE, and I want to import a texture pack for myself in the world. I am wondering if the texture pack will affect all players in the world when I apply it, even if they don't have the addon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If prompting other players to accept resource packs, like X-ray or Optifine, then players have the option to use these packs, but if they do not have this, then this means that they will have to download it to view the texture pack. Otherwise, the pack will be invisible to the other player.

Answer (score 0):

Ordinarily the answer would be “no”, however, there *is* a little toggle (in the Applied Resource Packs menu) that, when “on”, will force players to download the packs.